# Android - How to login through my website (using social network) and receive jwt token?

Tags: android, authentication, socialauth, social-authentication

I have laravel website with bunch of social logins, and want to use my website for social auth.

I want this to happen: when my app user click on social login button - my website social login url is started and after he successfully login it redirects to the app and he is logged in in my app.

I found lot of apps are doing so but I don't know how.

Edit: Simple login I've implemented using jwt. For network requests I use retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned you use a JWT token, do you have some form of a REST-API implemented?
If the answer to that question is yes, than maybe take a look at [Retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client), especially [this page](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android) (after taking the rest of the tutotial.)

Comment: I have rest api with retrofit. And also I have working simple login (username + password) with jwt. I want the easiest way to support social login on 6 social providers.

Comment: Might [this](https://github.com/Vanlalhriata/Laravel.SocialAuth/blob/master/readme.md) be what you are looking for? This could be easily implemented in Retrofit by passing a different parameter for each button. My knowledge of webdesign is fairly limited, so I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I need more android help, not php. That repo is using other approach, where I need to get social id in android and sent it to server. I want my android app don't know social id, only receive jwt from browser. I know apps that are doing so but dunno how to do it in my app.